# Matching and Replacing Sequences in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, match, matching

I am working on a task involving matching codes in a dataframe. Someone told me that if I lay out the relationships well, I can do this using graphs (data structure). Unfortunately I don't really know anything about graphs, so I don't know how to go about it.

I would like to match the 'codes' based on the following criteria:

1. Each 'id' should be assigned the oldest possible (earliest year) 'code', with one exception,  outlined below.
2. If two ids have a matching sequence of codes for several years, but one is missing values for earlier years, it will be assigned the earliest available code from the other id.
3. If two ids have a matching sequence of codes, but differ in later years, one of them has changed code in a meaningful way (these codes are distinct for my purpose). By finding the most frequently occurring sequence, we assume that any sequence other than that is a code change and retain that code instead of replacing it.

Here is an example of a frame and the desired output.

Given the initial left side, the right is the result I want to receive. Here, firm 3 has changed 'code' since its subsequence (1140 1140 1115 1115 1118) is less common (than 1140 1140 1115 1115 1117, which appears for two ids). There are matching subsequences for ids 1 and 2 (marked by one and two stars) which allow us to conclude that the two have the same initial code, and so we apply code 1140 to id 2.

```
year    id  code        year    id  code
2004    1   1140        2004    1   1140
2005    1   1140        2005    1   1140
2006    1   1115*       2006    1   1140
2007    1   1115*       2007    1   1140
2008    1   1117*       2008    1   1140
2006    2   1115**      2006    2   1140
2007    2   1115**      2007    2   1140
2008    2   1117**      2008    2   1140
2004    3   1140        2004    3   1140
2005    3   1140        2005    3   1140
2006    3   1115        2006    3   1140
2007    3   1115        2007    3   1140
2008    3   1118***     2008    3   1118
```

Are my matching rules too convoluted? Is graphs really the best way to do this - in which case where do I get started? Can you think of an easier way to do this?

I know it's a bit confusing so please let me know if clarification is needed. Thank you.

Edit:

I made a very rudimentary attempt. My attempt only succeeded in replacing values within specific ids, and even then I couldn't figure out how to assign this back to the original dataframe.

```
# group by id
by_id = df.groupby(['id'])

# replace with first code in each group
for name, group in by_id:

    selected = group['id'].reset_index()
    selected['id'] = selected['id'][0]
```

Comment: These rules are possible to implement. Have you made an attempt? If so, please share, as this will encourage more helpful responses.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I've added a very basic attempt that I made. I honestly don't even know where to start with matching subsequences. As you can see, I'm not even sure how to assign the changes back into my dataframe. But knowing this can be done is encouraging.